# How to pass the currently logged in user as default to a form

Tags: python, django

How do i pass the currently logged in user as default to a form?

I want the form to be pre-populated with the current user, but at the same time allow the user to change it (e.g. add the Customer for another user).

Here is my model:

```
class Customer (models.Model):

    shortname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    [...]
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    nextstep = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, default=(date.today() + timedelta(days=10)))

    def due_in(self):

        due_time = self.nextstep - date.today()
        overdue = due_time.days < 0
        return {'days': abs(due_time.days), 'overdue': overdue}

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Absolute URL des Partners"""
        return reverse('kundencenter:partner_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk}, current_app='kundencenter')
```

And my form:

```
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = [
            "shortname",
            "name",
            [...]
            "user",
        ]

        labels = {
            "shortname": 'Customer Shortname',
            "name": 'Full Name',
            }
```

And my view:

```
class CustomerCreateView(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    """Adds a new customer."""
    model = Customer
    template_name = 'customercenter/generic_new.html'
    form_class = CustomerForm
    success_message = "Customer %(name)s added."
```

Comment: Please show your view.

Comment: try to use save function or decorator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending Arpit Solanki's answer, you can add/override `get_initial` method  since you are using a Class Based View:

```
def get_initial(self):
    initial_data = super(CustomerCreateView, self).get_initial()
    initial_data.update({'user':self.request.user})
    return initial_data
```

Comment: Saved from writing code everywhere. Compact and sweet

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! Worked like a charm and is elegant. One note: The super-function takes in the view (CustomerCreateView), not the form (CustomerForm)...

Answer (score 3):

You can use initial in your form while rendering the form.

```
form = CustomerForm(initial={'user':request.user})
```

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) for more details.